# Excel: Have X-axis formatted to show ranges of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I'm attempting to graph values using a PivotChart, but the values range anywhere from 1 to 1000 and the specific values aren't too important, so I want them to be grouped from 1 to 100, 101 to 200, etc. The other variable would be "stacked" on top of others, but I'm having trouble getting the x-axis to do 1 to 100 etc, instead it currently shows the actual number.

My current Data, Pivot Table, and chart:
[image: My current Data, Pivot Table, and chart look like this]

I want it to look **something** like this:
[image: I want it to look __something__ like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it in the chart, need to add a new column to your raw data, with this formula:
`=INT(A2/100)*100 & " to " & (INT(A2/100)+1)*100`
[image]